# bootstrap 5 how do you collapse a column if it's empty

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do I get my 2 div column to be collapsed vertically (not take up the space on page) if it's empty. So if column 2 is empty, column 3 should slide over and fill that space.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">first col</div>
  <div class="col">collapse this if empty</div>
  <div class="col">third col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: vertically, and the 3rd column should slide over and fill remaining space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `col-auto` to shrink a column to the width of its content. If it doesn't contain any content it will "collapse". However, this will cause adjacent columns to expand (grow)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">first col</div>
        <div class="col-auto"></div>
        <div class="col">third col</div>
    </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/HfcKZmHE27

Comment: yeah, that would be nice too bc when there is content it would be nice if it was col-2

Comment: yes, just change the first column to col-auto also